# Search Unix file name by positions of the characters in file name

Tags: shell, file, unix, search

I have 2 files.

```
`File 1 = ABC2019120601C`
`File 2 = ABC2019120611C`
```

If I type ls -l ABC*C it will output all 2 files.
Is there a way to find files by exact position of the character?

```
For example
1st position = A
2nd position = B
3rd position = C
and 14th position = C
```

Then it will output only the file `ABC2019120601C`

```
Please help if this is possible
```

Thanks

Comment: You should ask this on: https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: ok let me ask.  Thanks

Comment: in your example you'll still get both files!

Comment: which shell are you using? It may change the answers (sh, ksh, csh, bash...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash globbing has more than just `*`, e.g. `?`, which means  "any single character":

```
$ ls -1 ABC*C
ABC2019120601C
ABC2019120611C
$ ls -1 ABC????????0??
ABC2019120601C
$ ls -1 ABC????????1??
ABC2019120611C
```

Comment: Might be informative to mention the wildcards can also be combined, so if OP is not interested in characters after the 14th, he could more simply use `ls -1 ABC????????0*`

Answer (score 0):

On surface, the ASK is to find files regardless of the embedded date-time (probably YYYYMMDDHH). This translates into 'ABC[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]C' pattern. Either `printf` or `find` will work.

```
# Single Folder
printf '%s\n' ABC[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]C

# Multiple folders, deep search
find /folder1 /folder2 -name 'ABC[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]C'
```